# Curl not executing in php on server

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have this function to send message

> Code:

```
 public static function send($mobile,$otp,$country_code){
        $message = "Your 2-way authentication OTP is $otp";
         $curl = curl_init();
         $authKey  = App::environment('MSGAUTH');
         $senderId  = App::environment('SENDERID');
          curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
         CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.XXX.com/api/sendhttp.php?authkey=".$authKey."&mobiles=".$mobile."&country=$country_code&sender=".$senderId."&route=3&message=$message",
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
         CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
         CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
         CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
         CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
         CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
         CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
         CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
         CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
             "content-type: application/json"
         ),
         ));

         $response = curl_exec($curl);
         $err = curl_error($curl);

         curl_close($curl);

         if ($err) {
             return false;
         } else {
           return true;
         }
 }
```

Issue is i'm getting blank quotes in the error part and this code is working on my local system but on server control is going in the else part. When i print `$err` i get this output

[image]

Any solution to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any info in `$response` ?

Comment: @Luuk: It is returning false, i have ssl enabled on my server

Comment: Why is this setting `content-type: application/json` for a GET request with query string parameters?

Comment: @CBroe: It is working on my local system but on server it is not working, i tried removing `content-type: application/json` but the same issue on server

Comment: Can you make other, absolutely basic requests? Like for `https://example.com/` or something that should be reachable and respond with a 200 OK in any case. If not, then this might be an issue of server configuration/firewalling.

Comment: @CBroe: I have checked other request it is returning 200 in response

Comment: If `curl_exec` return false, then an error occured. `curl_error` should return a description (which it does not), Does `curl_errno` return a number ? (The site may return an error number which is not in the 'standard' list )